# Как разбить input на три части, чтобы правильно поддерживались состояния valid, invalid

Tags: html, css

Существует форма с `input`, которая при загрузке выглядит как на 1 картинке.
Необходимо, чтобы `input` и `label` поддерживало различные состояния (2 картинка):

1. при вводе текста
2. при валидном вводе текста
3. при невалидном вводе текста

Нужно, чтобы `label` для телефона находился выше `input`. 
Вторая проблема в том, что по умолчанию `input` сразу приобретает состояние либо `invalid`, игнорируя первоначальные свойства, либо игнорирует состояние `valid`.

[image: ![Форма при загрузке страницы][1]][1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
input:required:valid ~ label,
textarea:required:valid ~ label {
 color: #5d9f81;
}
input:required:valid,
textarea:required:valid {
 border: 1px solid #5d9f81;
 color: #5d9f81;
 box-shadow: none;
}
input:invalid ~ label,
textarea:invalid ~ label {
 color: #da5f5b;
}
input:invalid,
textarea:invalid {
 border: 1px solid #da5f5b;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: none;
}
input:focus ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label {
 color: #fff;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 color: #fff;
}
label {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 font-size: 13px;
}
input, 
textarea {
 width: 212px;
 height: 22px;
 padding: 11px 0 9px 11px;
 border: 1px solid #5a5b5c;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: transparent;
 color: #5a5b5c;
 font-size: 12.5px;
 outline: none;
}
.phone-country, .phone-code {
 width: 50px;
 margin-right: 4px;
}
.phone-number {
 width: 77px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-phone">
   <input class="phone-country" type="tel" name="country" pattern="[0-9]{3,3}" autocomplete="off" required />
   <input class="phone-code" type="tel" name="code" pattern="[0-9]{2,2}" autocomplete="off" required />
   <input class="phone-number" type="tel" name="number" pattern="[0-9]{7,7}" autocomplete="off" required />
   <label class="label-phone">Phone Number</label>
</div>
```

Comment: и где css? что за состояния?

Comment: сори не заметила, что он не вставился

Comment: не совсем понятно, label не меняет цвет потому что input из трех блоков или потому что не должен? вопрос из цикла "судить нельзя помиловать", расставляйте знаки препинания или формулируйте вопрос четче.

Comment: переформулировала вопрос

Comment: без js такой штуки не сделать. :valid :invalid не даст отобразить просто текст белым цветом. Хотя, если кто знает, было бы интересно, как реализовать без js.

Comment: @NeedHate, позволит. Посмотрите мой ответ. Проблема только с валидации пустого `input` с `required` атрибутом. Отдельно это состояние не выделить селекторами. `:empty` не сработает, а жаль.

Comment: @ VenZell, да я про это же. Комментарий написал сразу как столкнулся с этой проблемой, когда хотел решить этот вопрос. http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/EPqZjM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы обращаетесь к несуществующему `label`.
Я об этом селекторе: `input:invalid + label`

Посмотрите, внутри `div` у вас только `input` и среди них нет сестринского элемента `label`.

Но это только половина ошибки. Если вы переместите `label` внутрь `div`, чтобы срабатывал ваш селектор, `label` все равно будет перекрашиваться только когда последний `input` будет содержать ошибку.

Это связано с тем, что `+` обращается строго к следующему элементу, а за первым и вторым `input` у вас следует другой `input`, а не `label`.

Чтобы исправить это, используйте селектор `~`, который будет искать `label` среди сестринских элементов `input` ниже по DOM-дереву, не ограничиваясь только непосредственно следующим элементом.

Вот исправленный код:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

```css
/* Косметические стили */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #28292b;
  color: #5a5a5c;
}
.row input + input {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
input {
  background-color: #28292b;
  border: 1px solid #5a5a5c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #5a5a5c;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 60px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.phone-code,
.phone-country {
  width: 60px;
}
.phone-number {
  width: 90px;
}

/* Меняем местами input и label */
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row label {
  display: table-header-group;
}

/* !!!Внимание!!! */
/* Приоритет расположения правил ниже важен для стилизации! */

/* Раскрашиваем пустые input и связанный label */

input:required[value=""],
input:required[value=""] ~ label {
  color: #5a5a5c;
}
input:required[value=""] {
  border-color: #5a5a5c;
}

/* Раскрашиваем корректные input и связанный label */
input:valid,
input:valid ~ label {
  color: #69be97;
}
input:valid {
  border-color: #69be97;
}

/* Раскрашиваем ошибочные input и связанный label */
input:invalid,
input:invalid ~ label {
  color: #e7635e;
}
input:invalid {
  border-color: #e7635e;
}

/* Раскрашиваем input в фокусе и связанный label */
input:focus,
input:focus:valid,
input:focus:invalid,
input:focus ~ label,
input:focus:valid ~ label,
input:focus:invalid ~ label {
  color: #fff;
}
input:focus,
input:focus:valid,
input:focus:invalid {
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <input class="phone-country" type="tel" name="country" pattern="[0-9]{3}" required value="" />
  <input class="phone-code" type="tel" name="code" pattern="[0-9]{2}" required value="" />
  <input class="phone-number" type="tel" name="number" pattern="[0-9]{7}" required value="" />
  <label class="label-phone">Phone Number</label>
</div>
```

К сожалению, селекторы в css ищут обычные атрибуты, а не вычисляемые.
Именно поэтому необходима пара строчек на jquery для трансляции текущего значения `input` в атрибут `value`.

Без нее можно обойтись, если отказаться от серого цвета для незаполненного `input` и смириться с красным цветом, если у него есть атрибут `required` и зеленым, если этого атрибута нет.

**Теперь о порядке.**
Чем меньше приоритет у состояния, тем выше он находится в листинге.
`:invalid` следует за `:valid`, чтобы при любом незаполненном `input` из мнимой группы, вся группа принимала состояние <kbd>с ошибкой</kbd>, и `label` окрашивался в красный цвет.
Аналогично для `:focus`. Он расположен в самом конце, чтобы при принятии в фокус одного элемента, вся мнимая группа принимала состояние <kbd>в фокусе</kbd>, и `label` окрашивался в белый цвет.

p.s. очень жаль, что селектор `:empty` тут не работает...

Comment: Выше попыталась более развернуто написать задание: селектор ~ помог, но теперь нужно, чтобы label находился выше input, для этого я использовала для input  отдельный div и следующие параметры для общего div: display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;. Вторая проблема в том, что по умолчанию input сразу приобретает состояние invalid , игнорируя первоначальные свойства.

Comment: У вас `label` опять не там расположен. Я же говорил вам, он должен быть в одной обертке с input. Позже соберу рабочий пример, на основе которого вы сделаете свою верстку

Comment: @LeraGridina, я обновил ответ. Если он вас устраивает, отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста.